# Is there a way to save a filter in libreoffice calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I keep switching between unfiltering and filtering on these three checkboxes

[image]

Is there a way I can save this filter so that I could click only once and have my sheet filtered instead of clicking on each value and hitting ok ?

Is there a better solution to what I want to achieve ?

Comment: I found your question intriguing. The best I could come up with was to create an array from `N2:N999` containing `{=IF(K2:K999="En attente",1,IF(K2:K999="Entammée",1,K2:K999="Programmée"))}` and filter on the array `N1:N999` (assuming that 998 rows are enough for your data and that `N` is an unused column). To show all rows select `Non Blank` (one key press in the drop-down); to apply your filter select tick-box `1`, then `OK` (two key presses). Instead of numbers, you can obviously change the `IF` expression to output meaningful text for your three filter values.

Comment: I think I'm using an old version of libreoffice (4.2.8.2) where you can't edit your array after it has been set (that includes trying to delete it). You also can't delete any row or column after you try to edit the array, even the ones that don't cross or overlap the array. I ended up editing your formula to only check for the next K cell and copy that formula onall N cells. Works fine thanks !

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I've posted my original suggestion as an answer. I checked with my 4.4.2.2 version and I could delete columns between or outside the ones used in the formula. I could also delete rows below the array, but not within it, though I could delete rows and move cells up if I selected columns prior to the selection column (`A` to `M`, including the `État` column). Your preferred solution may be better for your circumstances, but you will need to remember to copy the formula whenever you add new rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question intriguing, but could not see an obvious solution.

The best I could come up with was to create an array from `N2:N999` containing:

```
{=IF(K2:K999="En attente",1,IF(K2:K999="Entammée",1,K2:K999="Programmée"))}
```

You can then filter on the array `N1:N999` (assuming that 998 rows are enough for your data and that `N` is an unused column):

- to show all rows select `Non Blank` (one key press in the drop-down);
- to apply your filter select tick-box 1, then OK (two key presses).

Note that selecting `Non Blank` works because all the cells have a formula, and are therefore non-blank.

Instead of numbers, you can obviously change the `IF` expression to output meaningful text to represent the group of three filter values.